# WordPress PHP loop increase div ID and restart it

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm working on a WordPress loop - the output is a 4-col-container, where each div has a class with an increasing number, in this case ".c-1, .c-2, .c-3 and .c-4"

I already figured it out how to increase the number to 4, but now I wanted to know how I can "restart" the number after the 4th time so that the class integer starts at 1 again for the next row.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 16,
);
$work = new WP_Query($args);

$i = 1;
while ($work->have_posts()) : $work->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="c-<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('work'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I hope you can help me, guys! I really appreciate any kind of suggestion on this one :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
$i = 1;
while ($work->have_posts()) : $work->the_post(); ?>
    //Reset $i to 1 when the counter reach the count of 4
    <?php if($i == 4) $i = 1; ?>
    <div class="c-<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('work'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, Ibrahim :) You solved my riddle! Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($i == 4) {
    $i = 1;
} else {
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$i++;` with `$i = $i % 4 + 1;`.